How can we calculate simple quantum tunneling processes from the path integral?
I've been reading through Altland and Simons' Condensed Matter Field Theory, and am confused a bit by their discussion on tunneling and instantons. However I don't quite understand how this relates to the "normal" tunneling techniques I am used to in the operator formalism, in particular WKB. The authors write that the instanton/semiclassical technique for the double potential well gives the same form of the tunneling amplitude as the WKB approximation. But WKB relies on energy eigenstates, whereas in the path integral there is no notion of energy. WKB only gives you an approximate eigenstate, from which one can calculate the ratio of the amplitudes in the reflected and transmitted regions to get the transmission coefficient, whereas the path integral only gives you access to overlaps like $<q_f|e^{-iHt/\hbar}|q_i>$. I don't see how these overlaps give you a notion of a "transmission coefficient" like the operator formalism. In the case (i.e. double potential well) where there are isolated local minima, such as a single point $q_m$, one can identify the overlap $<q_m | e^{iHt/\hbar}|q_m>$ as the amplitude to remain confined at the minimum, which gives a notion of tunneling. However, what about when there is an extended region of minima right next to each other? How does one define tunneling from the position eigenstate overlaps?
I think seeing a concrete problem would clarify a lot of things. For concreteness, consider the potential $V(q) = 0$ for $|q|>a$, $V(q) = f(q)$ for $|q|<a$ where $f(q)$ is some slowly-varying function. One can straightforwardly use the WKB approximation to calculate approximate energy eigenstates, from which the transmission coefficient as a function of energy can be calculated. How could one do the same calculation with the path integral method?

Which page in A&S?
